# how to use first attribute into second attribute from scala case class

Tags: scala, case-class

I have created a case class like this:

```
case class MyClass[T](attName: String, getter: (ResultSet) => T)
```

I intantiate two exemple like this:

```
val ex1 = MyClass("name", (rs: ResultSet) => rs.getString("name"))
val ex2 = MyClass("age", (rs: ResultSet) => rs.getInt("age"))
```

I would like to avoid to use two time name and age for each line. Do you have any idea to reuse attName in the second attribute? Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
class MyClass[T](name: String, getter: (ResultSet, String) => T) {
   def getIt(rs: ResultSet): T = getter(rs, name)
}

case object MyClassName extends MyClass[String]("name", _ getString _)
case object MyClassAge extends MyClass[Int]("age", _ getInt _)
```

Or just

```
val ex1 = new MyClass("name", _ getString _)
val ex2 = new MyClass("age", _ getInt _)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but what do you mean by: you shouldn't be making case classes without parameters. I have attName and getter parameter. And can I don't understantd how getIt def of you class is used into case object? Thanks

Comment: I think, I confused your question, with the other answer here :) It's the latter that was using parameter-less case classes, and case-to-case inheritance (which is no longer allowed). I'll take out that note from my answer. 
As for the `getIt`, it is supposed to be used in the same way `getter` was being used in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Two choices:

Create an object to hold the static things like column names and use them as variables:

```
  object MyClass {
    object DbKeys {
      val name = "name"
      val age = "age"
    }
  }

  case class MyClass[T](attName: String, getter: (ResultSet) => T)

  val ex1 = MyClass(DbKeys.name, (rs: ResultSet) => rs.getString(DbKeys.name))
  val ex2 = MyClass(DbKeys.age, (rs: ResultSet) => rs.getInt(DbKeys.age))
```

Still with the object but this time with an abstract class and 2 case classes. Notice that when instanciating you don't specify column names.

```
  object MyClassArg {
    object DbKeys {
      val name = "name"
      val age = "age"
    }
  }

  abstract class MyClassArg[T](attName: String, getter: (ResultSet) => T)
  case class MyClassName() extends MyClassArg(DbKeys.name, (rs: ResultSet) => rs.getString(DbKeys.name))
  case class MyClassAge() extends MyClassArg(DbKeys.age, (rs: ResultSet) => rs.getString(DbKeys.age))

  val ex1 = MyClassName
  val ex2 = MyClassAge
```

I prefer the second choice because it makes for a cleaner use. You can make `MyClassArg` non abstract to allow more flexibility.

The `getter` can also be further abstracted to avoid repeating the `rs.getString` part.